# Any attempt to execute vbs script generates a File Not Found Error

Tags: vbscript, wsh, wscript.shell

The specific error is:

> Script: \\dc\netlogon\folder\file.vbs
>
> Line: 0
>
> Char: 1
>
> Error: File not found
>
> Code: 800A0035
>
> Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

The file is at the location specified. Furthermore, the same error is generated when double clicking on the file directly. And if the file is copied to the local drive and double clicked. And if invoked from the command line with wscript. It appears to occur when ANY vbs is launched via ANY method.

WScript is not disabled through the registry.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out I was including other scripts using code like:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    executeGlobal .openTextFile(otherfile).readAll()
End With
```

This is the file that could not be found, but the parser choked - maybe because of the combination with the executeGlobal command - and gave me line 0 instead of the actual line.

So it turns out that line 0 probably references a combination of parsing error and inner reference file not found.